# Place SWF movie behind HTML content

Tags: html, flash, z-index

I'm trying to create a website which has a movie (SWF) that must be placed behind the navigation, however it isn't working. The movie isn't appearing behind, even when I played with the z-index attribute.

To explain what I'm trying to create, please, take a look at this image which describes the main elements of my website:

[image]

Can someone share a piece of code to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parameters to the object/ embed tags, along with the z-index parameters:

For object:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

For embed:

`wmode="transparent"`

Here's a good example: http://www.flashdesignerzone.com/tutorials/t1026.php